# Pickit 3 mplab_ipe with Mac OSX

Tags: pickit

I am trying to programme a PIC, but mplab_ipe will not recognise the programmer (the tool list is not populated), nor does running `sudo dmesg` . The programmer has 01.30.09 PIC18F firmware.

Any help appreciated